# Getting values from OleDbDataReader

Tags: c#, excel, oledbdatareader

I would like to know if it is possible to retrieve a specific value from `OleDbdataReader`.

For example, I import data from excel sheet which has 100 rows and 10 columns. Then I want the reader to get values from all the columns at specified row. Let's say I have a textbox, put random number into it(85), the reader finds this number in the first column and reads all the column values accordingly.

And, yes, if it is possible, could you please provide some guidance on how to do that.

So far I have only managed to get the reader to read all the values.

The main idea is that by changing value in textbox, reader would apply different set of values into method. Link to the picture from excel sheet to make it more clear:

https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/505x318q90/743/YIVGVf.jpg

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Model ThisModel = new Model();
        Beam ThisBeam = new Beam();

        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
        const string excelConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=@1;";
        const string connStringExtras = @"Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;Imex=1""";
        conn.ConnectionString = excelConnString.Replace("@1", "C:\\Users\\Andrejs\\Desktop\\API2.xls;") + connStringExtras;

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F "+
                "FROM [SHEET1$]", conn);
            OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                double X = (double)reader.GetValue(1);
                double Y = (double)reader.GetValue(2);
                CreatePadFooting(X, Y);
            }
        }
            catch
            {
            }

        ThisModel.CommitChanges();
    }
    private static void CreatePadFooting(double X, double Y)
    {
        Beam PadFooting1 = new Beam();

        PadFooting1.Name = "FOOTING";
        PadFooting1.Profile.ProfileString = "200*200";
        PadFooting1.Material.MaterialString = "K30-2";
        PadFooting1.Class = "8";
        PadFooting1.StartPoint.X = X;
        PadFooting1.StartPoint.Y = Y;
        PadFooting1.StartPoint.Z = 0.0;
        PadFooting1.EndPoint.X = X;
        PadFooting1.EndPoint.Y = Y;
        PadFooting1.EndPoint.Z = -500.0;
        PadFooting1.Position.Rotation = Position.RotationEnum.FRONT;
        PadFooting1.Position.Plane = Position.PlaneEnum.MIDDLE;
        PadFooting1.Position.Depth = Position.DepthEnum.MIDDLE;

        PadFooting1.Insert();
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's possible to do, yes.

Comment: As tyler says it is indeed possible.  Can you be a little clearer about what you want to do, also what have you tried so far.

Comment: Probably you need a WHERE in your SELECT query. Could you show the full code that selects rows from your excel file?

Comment: I have attached full code and link to picture to clarify what I intend to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an `If` statement to compare the value of first column and then read from Reader. Insert an If statement like this:

```
double randomValue = Convert.ToDouble(txtBoxRandomValue.Text); //get value to match and convert to double

try
    {
        conn.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F "+
            "FROM [SHEET1$]", conn);
        OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {

        if (randomValue == Convert.ToDouble(reader.GetValue(0))) //checking here the first column
         {
            double X = (double)reader.GetValue(1);
            double Y = (double)reader.GetValue(2);
            CreatePadFooting(X, Y);
         }
       }
    }
        catch
        {
        }
```